# dia de semana aparece en ingles en pdf yii2

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, yii2

Buen día

necesito saber como pongo el nombre del día de la semana en español, extraigo el nombre de la semana de esta forma

```
<td align="left" ><?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->fecha_hora, 'php:l'); ?></td>
```

la fecha es un datetime en la base de datos en MySQL, estoy trabajando con Yii2, por temas del servidor me toca crear una función pero me solicitan que primero valide con que numero empieza la semana pero no se como revisar eso

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Probaste cambiando el [locale en Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n#locale) o el [local en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php)?

Comment: no lo puedo cambiar por un tema del servidor

Answer (score 0):

Agrega al principio de tu archivo `/web/index.php`

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_CL.utf8') or die('Locale not found');
```